# Selenium - Can not get url from product page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get all information from [this product's page](https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/collection/ofertas-mujer-ropa-v2).

Currently I can get name, brand name, price.. But I can't get the product url.

I was trying with:

```
product_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'testId-pod-displaySubTitle-')]")
```

And then capture this like: `product_name.get_attribute('href')`, but without success.

Why I can't get this information from this attribute? what am I failing at?

Answer (score 0):

The products are wrapped inside a `div` with id `testId-searchResults-products`, so you can use to find all `div` elements within this `div` and then fetch the `href` from the `a` tag to get the results-

This piece of code (tested on a Mac with Selenium beta 4) returns all the product links

```
driver.get("https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/collection/ofertas-mujer-ropa-v2")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,'testId-Dropdown-desktop-button')))

sectionclass = driver.find_element(By.ID,"testId-searchResults-products")
alldivs = sectionclass.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.jsx-4001457643.search-results-4-grid.grid-pod")

for i in range(len(alldivs)):
    all_text = alldivs[i].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div > a').get_attribute("href")
```

And the output is something link this

> https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/product/15009660/Vestido-Fluido-Punos-Elasticos-Prarie-Mujer/15009666

> https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/product/882018735/Chaqueta-Mujer/882018753

> https://www.falabella.com/falabella-cl/product/881384821/Pantalon-de-Algodon-Mujer/881384856

.
.
.
.

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `product_name` list like this :

```
product_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'testId-pod-displaySubTitle-')]")
```

You could get `product url` using the `ancestor a tag` :

```
product_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'testId-pod-displaySubTitle-')]")
for product in product_name:
    url = product.find_element_by_xpath(".//ancestor::a").get_attribute('href')
    print(url)
```